# Get table header (th) on tooltip of table cell (td) when hovering over cell

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have Table of 3 columns - when I hover on column 3 the tooltip should show me its table header `th` value .

Here's what I have so far (not working):

Javascript:

```
$('#waypointsTable td').hover(function() {
  var $td='td';
  var $th = $td.closest('tbody').prev('thead').find('> tr > th:eq(' + $td.index() + ')');
});
```

html:

```
<table id="waypointsTable" border="1">
<tbody>
<tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>some text 1</td>
     <td>some text 1</td>
      <td>some text 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>some text 2</td>
     <td>some text 2</td>
      <td>some text 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>some text 3</td>
     <td>some text 3</td>
      <td>some text 3</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: i am fresher in js and jquery can u please give full explanation and implementation thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the javascript provided:

- First, if you're using `.prev("thead")` then you need to change your html so that it has a `<thead>`.
- Next, use `mouseover` rather than `hover` - not much difference, but you don't need to do anything on 'hover-out' so no need for that.
- Use `var td = $(this)` to get the current cell
- Use your existing code (mostly) to get the related `th`
- Then, use `td.attr("title", th.text())` to set the tooltip on the cell.

Put together:

```js
$('#waypointsTable tbody td').on("mouseover", function() {
  var td = $(this);
  var th = td.closest('tbody').prev('thead').find('> tr > th:eq(' + td.index() + ')');
  td.attr("title", th.text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="waypointsTable" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>some text 1</td>
      <td>some text 1</td>
      <td>some text 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>some text 2</td>
      <td>some text 2</td>
      <td>some text 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>some text 3</td>
      <td>some text 3</td>
      <td>some text 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You could do this on startup instead as the tooltip won't change once set.